# How to define a field of a model to have a choice from another field of another model of another app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have two models defined in two different apps.
I want to have a choice option for a particular field in a model, which is deriving those attributes from another field of a model in another app.

eg: I have a model "**Inventory**" that has a field ***'title'***.

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, default='')
    ....
```

I also have another model '**Invoice**' that has a field ***'line_one'**.* Both these models are located in different apps.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
   line_one = models.CharField('Line 1', max_length=120)
   ....
```

I created a Django form for adding the Invoice details. I want a choice option for **line_one** that has all the values stored in the Inventory.title field so that the user can only select those values from a dropdown menu.
How can I implement this?
Thanks.

Edit: I referenced **line_one** to the field **title** of the **Inventory** model and it seems to work but it isn't exactly showing the name of the attributes but showing, "Inventory Object(7)", "Inventory Object(8)"

```
    line_one = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, to_field='title', default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You like to get the strings as choices, but not an actual reference/ForeignKey to the Inventory, right?

Comment: An actual foreign key reference sounds good. I tried using, 
`line_one = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, to_field='title,...')`
But I get an error when I go to add the invoice saying, 
**OperationalError at /admin/inventory/inventory/
no such column: invoicecemgmt_invoice.line_one_id**
I am not sure what it means?

Comment: If you change your models, you need to make & run migrations for the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models

Comment: @JanMalte The dropdown box is working but it says, **Inventory Object(7)** and **Inventory Object(8)**.  
The line of code in my models.py is, 
`line_one = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, to_field='title', default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with your changed code, as this might be helpful for others.

Comment: I've updated the answer below to have a solution for both options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use a `CharField` for `line_one`

```py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, default='')
    # ...


class Invoice(models.Model):
   line_one = models.CharField('Line 1', max_length=120)
   # ...


class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    line_one = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ['line_one', ] # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # populate the choices from the Inventory model objects
        self.fields['line_one'].widget.choices = [(i.title, i.title) for i in Inventory.objects.all()]
        # or
        self.fields['line_one'].widget.choices = [(t,t) for t in Inventory.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)
```

#### Use a `ForeignKey` for `line_one`

If you like to use a `ForeignKey`, it is necessary to have unique values for `Inventory.title`.

```py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, default='')
    # ...

    # The __str()__ method of an object is used by django
    # to generate the labels for a Select input widget
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Invoice(models.Model):
   line_one = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, to_field='title', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # ...


class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ['line_one', ] # ...

    # no need for any form adjustments,
    # as django uses a select input as default for ForeignKey fields
```

Comment: The foreign key method worked! But when I use the Charfield and use the code that you mentioned then I get this runtime error.
`RuntimeError at /invoice/add_invoice/
super(): no arguments
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoice/add_invoice/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value: 
super(): no arguments`

Comment: `..\forms.py, line 69, in __init__
  super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
Variable Value
__class__ 
<class 'invoicecemgmt.forms.InvoiceForm'>
args 
Error in formatting: AttributeError: 'InvoiceForm' object has no attribute '_errors'
kwargs 
{}`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I’ve fixed the code in the answer.